# Configuring Admin in Rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, admin

So I've implemented the rails admin gem, and even with the cancan gem, I can't figure out a way to password protect localhost:3000/admin

Could someone give me a step by step guide for doing this? I can't really find a view or controller for the admin panel, so I'm not sure how to password protect it.

Comment: did you add `devise_for :admins`?

Comment: Yeah I put that in my config file

Answer (score 0):

This page describes how you should be using Cancan : https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/CanCan

```
# in config/initializers/rails_admin.rb
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.authorize_with :cancan
end
```

Their ability.rb example may be a bit more than you need this is mine :

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.has_role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
      can :access, :rails_admin   # grant access to rails_admin
      can :dashboard              # grant access to the dashboard
    end
  end

end
```

You must then give the admin role to a user.

you can do this at the rails console as so :

```
user = User.find(1) #find user with ID 1
user.add_role :admin #assign role
user.has_role? :admin #should evaluate to True
```